# Why should i give a name to an If Statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, naming

I just discovered that i can give a name to For and While statements. I understand that it is useful if you want to break or continue a specific loop.
But why should i give a name to an If?? It looks useless

```
name: if(true){
    //do something
}
```

This compiles without problems

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE!  Do not use this pattern!  Goto like this is evil!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a code block with a name, you can use break to exit it, that is the use I have found for naming blocks.

```
name: if(true) {
    // do something
    if(/* condition */) {
        break name;
    }
    // do more
}
```

it also works without the if:

```
name: {
    // do something
    if(/* condition */) {
        break name;
    }
    // do more
}
```

This comes up in my work when there are a set of guard conditions on some logic, and another set of logic that will be fallen down into regardless of the outcome of the guards.

A further example where alternative structures are more difficult to read and modify:

```
block: if(/* guard */) {

  // prep work

  if(/* guard */) {
    break block;
  }

  // prep work

  if(/* guard */) {
    break block;
  }

  // real work
}
```

though usually I use a bare block and not an if.

Comment: +1 Never seen that before. Although, wouldn't putting the code you want to break past in an else block accomplish the same?

Comment: in some cases, however the form (guard, calculate, guard, calculate, guard, work) is much easier to read this way.

Comment: I personally still think I prefer the if-else structure, but now I've learned something new :-).

Comment: It is a way to simulate some `goto`s.

Answer (score 7):

You can use labels before any statement block. This is maybe most commonly used for loops, but is perfectly valid elsewhere.

Comment: +1, to add to your answer, this link has some examples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: mmm ok but this doesn't answer to my question :D is there any practical use of naming an if?

Answer (score 2):

[Sarah Happy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904547/why-should-i-give-a-name-to-an-if-statement/4904625#4904625)'s answer is actually more correct than mine in showing that you can use `break` to break code blocks, in addition to loops, so I suggest looking at her answer.

---

That is indeed a [label](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), which as you said is for For and While loops. It is valid elsewhere, but I'd like to add that you **cannot** use

```
goto name;
```

While `goto` is a reserved word, Java does **not** support goto, but it does support it in the form of labeled loops coupled with `break` and `continue`.

If you expanded your code sample to include a goto, like:

```
 name: if(true){
    //do something
  }
 goto name;
```

You'd get errors, saying both `illegal start of expression` and `not a statement`

Alternatively, if you tried to use `continue` with your label, but without a loop, like:

```
 name: if(true){
    //do something
  }
 continue name;
```

You'd get `undefined label: name`

So in terms of the compiler, having a label without a loop is ok, but it's pretty much worthless without a loop.

Comment: it has the same use as multi-level breaks in nested loops.

Comment: @Oneiros: No, it's *not* useless; this answer seems to be wrong -- see Sarah's answer.

Comment: Can you unselect my answer for Sarahs?

Answer (score 0):

Just like breaking a loop you might want to jump back or toward an if statement.  Although whenever you start thinking about this, look into creating a new method instead.