# why does Java allow you to break the current line?

Tags: java, break

In short, **why is this allowed?**

```
label1: while (condition)
label2:     if (condition)
label3:         break label3;
```

I can understand labelling the `while` so you can end prematurely, or the `if` so you can break one `if` and not another, but why `break`? When would you need to `break` out of the current `break`?

After testing, I find that `label3: break label3;` runs, but does nothing and continues onto the next line. **What's the function of this?**

Also note that Java doesn't let you break all statements. For instance, `label: Object o = new Object();` gives compiler errors stating that it's not a statement, and that a `;` was expected, even though it does run `Object`'s constructor method (and, as we see in [Why does Java allow for labeled breaks on arbitrary statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099628/why-does-java-allow-for-labeled-breaks-on-arbitrary-statements), Java allows you to label method calls; `label: new Object();` compiles just fine).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7

Comment: Simplicity of language definition? Prohibiting it at the language level would be more complex; but allowing it seems fairly harmless. An alternative would be to flag it during code analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1: Why does Java allow this?

As with all language design questions, the only way to get a definitive answer is to *ask the designers*.

But in this case, this is a useless but harmless edge case on an otherwise useful construct.  Since it does no real harm, there is little need to disallow it.

Indeed, there would be a harm in *disallowing* it.  A language restriction that removed this (harmless) edge case would:

- make it harder for folks who are building tools that *generate* Java code,
- be extra work for the group of people writing the java specification, and
- be extra work for the groups of people who build Java compilers.

---

> Q2: What is the purpose?

It doesn't have a purpose *per se*.  The statement `label: break label;` does nothing useful.

But that's fine, there are lots of other ways of writing Java programs that don't do anything useful; e.g. `if (true) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement is talked about by the [JLS, Section 14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15):

> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the
>   innermost enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the
>   immediately enclosing method or initializer; this statement, which is
>   called the break target, then immediately completes normally.
>
> To be precise, a break statement with no label always completes
>   abruptly, the reason being a break with no label.
>
> If no switch, while, do, or for statement in the immediately enclosing
>   method, constructor, or initializer contains the break statement, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> A break statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control
>   to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; this statement, which is called the break
>   target, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the break
>   target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.
>
> To be precise, a break statement with label Identifier always
>   completes abruptly, the reason being a break with label Identifier.
>
> A break statement must refer to a label within the immediately
>   enclosing method, constructor, or initializer. There are no non-local
>   jumps. If no labeled statement with Identifier as its label in the
>   immediately enclosing method, constructor, or initializer contains the
>   break statement, a compile-time error occurs.

There is nothing that states that the label to which `break` breaks can't be labelled to something inside the current block.  You can always just say `break;` to break out of the innermost contained block.

And `break` doesn't break out of an `if` -- it must be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for`, per the JLS above.

The reason that `label: Object o = new Object();` doesn't work is because `Object o = new Object();` isn't a statement -- it's a declaration.  The [JLS, Section 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) talks about that:

> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement.

Comment: *"And break doesn't break out of an if -- it must be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for`, per the JLS above."* - **That is NOT what it says!**  What it actually says is that an `break` *without a label* must be inside a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for`, and a `break` *with a label* does not have this restriction.